# Developing a Wordpress plugin like a component in Joomla

Tags: plugins

My mission:
I have a system that could have been a standalone website, but I would like to be a part of an existing CMS so that I can avoid writing my own user management system, forum, blog system, etc. I could have made it as a component in Joomla! as I have been working with that before, but unfortunately I do not like Joomla! and have therefore chosen Wordpress.

My problem:
My system should both have admin pages and front end pages available inside my Wordpress page. I have been able to create a plug-in and add admin pages, but I have yet to find out how to make the front end. One solution could be to create a page-template in my chosen theme, but as I want to seperate my component from Wordpress as much as possible, and also want it to be theme-independent this is a bad solution.

How can you help:
Please provide me with a simple example or guide me towards either a tutorials or an existing Wordpress plug-ins for me to look at to be able to make my plug-in. Bear in mind that this plug-in should only be used on my page and that I only want to use Wordpress as a shell for the plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your custom [widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widget_API), template function or [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

By template function I mean something like this:

```
<?php function the_my_template_function(){ ?>
    <div>My content printed out</div>
<?php } ?>
```

which a WordPress user will call from it's theme by inserting this piece of code into his theme:

```
<?php the_my_template_function(); ?>
```

It's a common approach.